# CSS translate to the top left of the browser window

Tags: css

I am trying to create an animation that takes a div and translates it to the top left of the browser window. Can this be done?

I have a block of vertical navigation links that look like the following, when the `Expand` link is clicked, I currently add the `open` class to the div with `add-open-class`. From there I want the div to slide to the top left of the screen.

```js
let generes = document.querySelector('.expand')
generes.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let accordion = generes.closest('.add-open-class')
  accordion.classList.toggle('open')
})
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.open {
  animation: openAnimation .2s both ease-in;
}

@keyframes openAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Nav Item</a>
<a href="#">Nav Item</a>
<a href="#">Nav Item</a>
<a href="#">Nav Item</a>
<a href="#">Nav Item</a>
<a href="#">Nav Item</a>
<div class="add-open-class">
  <a href="#" class="expand">Expand</a>
  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#">Sub Nav Item</a>
    <a href="#">Sub Nav Item</a>
    <a href="#">Sub Nav Item</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :/ now you changed the question. But not showing how exactly the HTML with `.open` element looks. Neither what's the entire `.open` CSS (entire and relevant to the question)

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```css
.open {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    animation: openAnimation 2s both ease-in;
}

@keyframes openAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translate(calc(100vw - 50px), calc(100vh - 50px));
  }

  100% {
      transform:translate(0%,0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="open"></div>
```

**Update:** Animate (transform/translate) only inside wrap

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 40px;
    border: solid 2px green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}

.open {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    animation: openAnimation 2s both ease-in;
}

@keyframes openAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translate(calc(300px - 20px), calc(150px - 20px));
  }

  100% {
      transform:translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="open"></div>
</div>
```

With your code something like this:

```js
let generes = document.querySelector('.expand')
generes.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let accordion = generes.closest('.add-open-class')
  accordion.classList.toggle('open')
})
```

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 2px green;
}

.add-open-class {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 2px orange;
}

.add-open-class.open {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border: solid 2px fuchsia;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.open {
  animation: openAnimation .2s both ease-in;
}

@keyframes openAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <div class="add-open-class">
      <a href="#" class="expand">Expand</a>
      <div class="accordion">
        <a href="#">Sub Nav Item</a>
        <a href="#">Sub Nav Item</a>
        <a href="#">Sub Nav Item</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: at 0%, is there a way to use the current position?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn sure. Just add a `.wrap` and position it relative. See updated answer.

Comment: Mine is getting close, but when I do this, it snaps to nearly the top of the page (right below the first link), then transitions the rest of the way to the top

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn must be positioning problem.